# Can the Starfleet standard of memory be converted to bytes?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

During the modern Star Treks (relative to the timeline, e.g mid 24th century onwards, especially in Voyager), memory capacity is measured in 'quads,' 'kiloquads,' 'megaquads,' 'gigaquads' etc, but there is no standard among these that can be followed and used as a real system. For example, when the EMH in Voyager was transmitted back to the Alpha Quadrant, he had to leave behind 12 megaquads of information to fit within the bandwidth, and we also know that when voyager received a message back through the Midas Array at another point, they were able to retrieve 68 kiloquads of data. If this is the maximum data that could be reconstructed, we can place the EMH program at up to 12.5 megaquads in size, if we leave room to compensate for people rounding numbers to the nearest megaquad. At another time, however, we learn that the EMH matrix has destabilised because it had exceeded 1000 terraquads of information. If this follows the same scale as today's bytes, 1000 terraquads is at least 80,000,000 times larger than what we know the EMH program to be. This leads me to believe that the quad system doesn't follow the same laws as the byte system, so does anybody know what system it does follow, and how to convert this into bytes?

Thanks to anybody who answers, this has been bugging me for a long time.

[This is where I sourced my data.](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Quad)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find anywhere in the TNG Technical Manual where there's a behind-the-scenes explanation of quads, but it seems reasonable to assume it was made up so that they wouldn't be beholden to modern-day computing terms and then sound laughable in the real world as technology marched on. I don't know where Memory Alpha sourced the background information section in the linked page on Quads, but it does essentially answer your question. No, there's no known conversion factor, and Voyager used the unit of measure confusingly.

Comment: @Dranon Yep that's pretty much what Okuda said in the tech manual.

Comment: I found Voyager to be pretty bad about throwing numbers around with no real thought for consistency.

Comment: You appear to be assuming that the EMH program was among the 68 kQ Voyager was able to "reconstruct" from the transmission Earth sent back.  But, *unless I'm forgetting a critical plot point,* (and I won't write that off entirely, since this in Voyager) I don't see why Earth would need to include the EMH again - the EMH that was sent through to Earth was a copy, and copying data doesn't destroy the original. Even if the EMH was being used as some sort of "container file" both ways, the EMH on Voyager should remain intact, so the 68 kQ of data recovered need not be related to him at all.

Comment: @Steve-O That's a good point, but we also learn that the total data that they send through about their experience is 'hundreds of kiloquads,' meaning that my calculations about the different sizes of the EMH remain the same. I could very well be wrong, thank you for questioning me.

Comment: @Dranon thanks you for answering!

Comment: @Brandon sadly, I've observed that as well.

Comment: Pure speculation: maybe it simply cannot be converted one to one in a way that makes sense. Think of the information that needs to be transmitted to beam one person. You not only have to transfer the mass, but also a lot of things (for instance the state of subatomic particles) that cannot be expressed in ones and zeroes.

Comment: @Twinkles that's a good point

Comment: @CaptainJ.LPicard My comment isn't much of an answer, I'm afraid, otherwise I would have actually answered. If I find a primary source when I have time to do the research, I'll make a real answer.

Comment: @zabeus If you can find the quote from the tech manual, make it an answer and I'll happily upvote it. I thought there was a note about why quads were made up in there, but I couldn't find it. Admittedly, I was pretty busy last night and only skimmed it.

Comment: @Dranon Thanks! Either way, I appreciate how you took the time to propose a theory!

Comment: I suspect that the unit of measure, and its equivalent in our units, is purposefully left undefined so that ten years after the show's production is ended we are not routinely exceeding those amounts, centuries prior to the show's setting.  I remember when I first read of a CPU that could address 4 gigs of RAM.  At the time I thought that only a supercomputer would ever have that much RAM, but now you can buy them at many stores.

Comment: @EvilSnack That's a good point!

Comment: @Valorum Not at all, sorry, I just forgot to accept!

Comment: Cheers for the accept

Comment: @Valorum No problem, and thanks for answering!

Comment: I don't remember where I heard it,  but I seem to remember something about their computer system using quantum states to store memory, and that there are 4 states instead of the binary 1 and 0.  If this is actually the case, it would account for the difficulty, as the architecture would be completely different, requiring double the possible values for each digit, and allowing for much higher information density.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting directly from the [TNG Encyclopedia](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Encyclopedia), the short answer is that **it's not a convertible unit**, and quite intentionally so.

> **Kiloquad:**
>   *Unit of measure of data storage and transmission in Federation computer systems. ("Realm of Fear" (TNG]). **No, we don't
>   know how many bytes are in a kiloquad. We don't even want to know. The
>   reason the term was invented was specifically to avoid describing the
>   data capacity of Star Trek's computers in 20th-century terms.** It was
>   feared by technical consultant Mike Okuda that any such attempt would
>   look foolish in just a few years, given the current [rate of progress
>   in that field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law).*

For the record, the term is used in a wildly inconsistent fashion ranging from a few kiloquads in the [TNG Technical Manual](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual) up to [*millions* of teraquads](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/613.htm) in Voyager.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for answering!